# Should keypress event work in Angular directive on FF?

Tags: angularjs, firefox, angularjs-directive

I have a simple directive that prevents non-numeric entry in `input[type="number"]` boxes. It works in Chrome, but not in Firefox. In FF, no input is allowed whatsoever, not just non-numeric characters. Anyone know why? And any simple alternatives?

```
validationModule.directive('naturalNumber', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element) {

            element.bind('keypress', function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: can you post example in Fiddle/Plunker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `event.keyCode` always return `0`, so everything is getting ignored. [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/keypress) that `charCode`, `keyCode` and `which` properties are deprecated and suggest to use `key` instead, but it's not implemented yet.

To fix the problem, use `which`, which seems to work just fine:

```
element.bind('keypress', function (event) {
    if (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

You should probably consider how browsers handle key codes: check for all possible property names or include jQuery before AngularJS to normalize events.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/goyos/2/).

**P.S.**: numpad keys don't work, users might not like that. I suggest to filter input via [`ngModelController`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController) utilities, that would be more Angular-way.

Comment: The problem with `ngModelController` is that it doesn't work on `input[type="number"]`. The non-numeric keys are eaten up by the browser and never make it to the parsers.